# How to spread elements homogeneously in an array with a specific length

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, logic

I'm trying to create an array with a specific length from another array that has length < the new array thats i want create, not just that, i want the elements be spread homogeneously into the array

examples whats im looking for:

*i have: `909 | 802 | 913`

what i'm expecting in the new array with length = 7 :

`909 | U | U | 802 | U | U | 913`

another example: 
*we have:

`101 | 203 | 144 | 135`

array with length = 6 expectation :

`101 | U | 203 | 144 | U | 135`

*we have:

`909 | 802 | 913`

array with length = 5 expectation :

`909 | U | 802 | U | 913`

*we have:

`909 | 802 | 913`

array with length = 8 expectation :

`909 | U | U | 802 |  U  | U | U | 913` or

`909 | U | U |  U  | 802 | U | U | 913` its ok, the two expectations is correct

`U = undefined`/null

In any language the algorithme can be, i dont have a problem,
the code maybe something like this:

```
function spreadHomogeneously(newSize: number/*must be bigger than the length of elements/numbers*/, elements: Array<number>): Array<number> /*return is a homogeneous array*/{

  //logic

}
```

My attempt:

```
function spreadHomogeneously(newSize, elements){
  if (newSize <= elements.length){
    return elements
  }else{
    var array = new Array(newSize);
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { 
      array[i*newSize/elements.length] = elements[i]
    }
    return array;
  }
}

console.log(spreadHomogeneously(6, [1, 3, 5]));
```

output: 
index 0: 1

index 2: 3

index 4: 5

but not this what exactly i'm searching for

i hope thats the idea is clear, 
Thanks

Comment: yea thanks, i added the closest attempt to the result thats im searching for

Comment: Not sure why the question got down voted.  Question is clear enough, but am curious of the use case, as there might be better means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an integer variable that increases with `newSize-1` in each iteration over the original array. Count the number of times `oldSize-1` fits in that value: that will be the index where to put the value in the new array. To calibrate this, let that variable start with a value that is half of `oldSize-1`, so that in the last iteration it will have the value `(oldSize-1)/2 + (oldSize-1) * (newSize-1)`, which translates to index `newSize-1`, which is exactly where the last original value should end up.

The key difference with your attempt is the `-1`. This is because the index-distance between the first and last value in the resulting array is not `newSize`, but `newSize-1`. The same reasoning applied to the original array means that you must use `oldSize-1`.

Here is the code:

```js
function spreadHomogeneously(newSize, elements) {
    let div = elements.length - 1;
    newSize--;
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0, j = div>>1; i < elements.length; i++, j+=newSize) {
        result[Math.floor(j/div)] = elements[i];
    }
    return result;
}

// demo with same data (string as iterable), but increasing newSize
for (let newSize = 5; newSize < 18; newSize++) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(spreadHomogeneously(newSize, "abcde")));
}
```